# JPanel image and components

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jcomponent, imageicon

I would like to have image on my JPanels an also have components such as JSlider and JRadioButton on my JPanel. I derived a class from JPanel and overrided method paintComponent as you see. This is a good way to have image on JPanel.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    /*create image icon to get image*/
    ImageIcon imageicon = new ImageIcon(imageFile); //getClass().getResource(imageFile)
    Image image = imageicon.getImage();

    /*Draw image on the panel*/
    super.paintComponent(g);

    if (image != null)
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
}
```

However I have some problems. When I add components such as JSlider, JRadioButton or another JPanel on my ImagePanel; this component's background remains as default and not background picture. I don't know how to set this image as background of this components. 
please guide me.

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must set opaque properties of other component to false.

```
jRadioButton.setOpaque(false);
```

for example :

[image: ImagePanel with RadioButton on it.]

Answer (score 1):

```
jRadioButton.setOpaque(false);
```

Will work for many look-and-feels, but if you want it to work with Nimbus you should also set the background color to be transparent:

```
jRadioButton.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613603/java-nimbus-laf-with-transparent-text-fields) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't `setOpaque(false)` for all the other components help?