# Background color in Glazed List and Nimbus

Tags: java, autocomplete, combobox, nimbus, glazedlists

I use a autocomplete feature for comboboxes from Glazed Lists. It's pretty usefull. I also use nibus L&F. But it ignores JCombobox.setBackground(Color). Is there any way to force backgroundcolor to be for example red using nimbus?

Examplecode:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JComboBox cbox = new JComboBox();
    String[] strs = {"Nowarro", "Klamat", "Den", "NKR"};
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
    } catch (Throwable e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    AutoCompleteSupport.install(cbox, GlazedLists.eventList(Arrays.asList(strs)));
    cbox.setBackground(Color.RED); // NO EFFECT!!!
    frame.getContentPane().add(cbox);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Color color = UIManager.getColor
      ("ComboBox:\"ComboBox.renderer\"[Selected].background");
```

for [Nimbus](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/color.html) you have to override nimbus UI default more [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html)

Answer (score 1):

ComboBoxes are made up of multiple components. You need to set the background color on the actual editor component in the combo box:

```
cbox.getEditor().getEditorComponent().setBackground(Color.red);
```

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613603/java-nimbus-laf-with-transparent-text-fields It looks like Nimbus has transparent text fields that you'll need to set to be opaque.